# 1km Grid misaligned. QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules, alignment

I have downloaded a 1km grid shapefile specifically for Cyprus.  When I add this layer, it is severely misaligned i.e. the grid lines are about 30degrees off north.  I guess this is a projection issue?  How do I correct this?

The grid is in "Inverse Of Europe Equal Area 2001 + ETSR89 to WGS 84 (1)" projection.  I got the grid from here:  https://sdi.eea.europa.eu/catalogue/srv/api/records/1e72c34c-32cc-4e8f-a668-8fe5ac40ec6d

I thought I had set the CRS in the project as WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator, but when I check the properties, it says no CRS, and I can't get that to change.  Can't see how to attach a screenshot to this comment.  Have tried setting the project CRS to WGS 84, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: You;ll need to tell us what projection the lines should be in, what they are in in your project and what your project CRS is, a screenshot would also be useful and a link to where you downloaded the data from